# Request Body Validation for PATCH when object is null vs object not present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-validator

The issue that I am having here is with the HTTP PATCH method since it allows partial updates.

I have a request Body as below.

```
{
    "userAssociationStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "accountHolderAssociationStatus": "ACTIVE",
}
```

Bean for request Mapping:-

```
public class PatchRequestVO {

    @CheckEnum(message = "Enumeration value is not found for userAssociationStatus.", enumValue = { "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE" })
    private String userAssociationStatus;

    @CheckEnum(message = "Enumeration value is not found for accountHolderAssociationStatus.", enumValue = { "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE" })
    private String accountHolderAssociationStatus;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The check enum is a custom annotation that validates if the value being passed is an exact match to one of the element from the enumValue list.

The problem I am facing is with the two below request's.

```
{
    "accountHolderAssociationStatus": "ACTIVE"
}
```

In the above request the **userAssociationStatus** is not present so since it is a PATCH i will ignore that and just update the other status.

The next request is

```
{
    "userAssociationStatus": null,
    "accountHolderAssociationStatus": "ACTIVE"
}
```

In this scenraio I want to throw enum not found since the the object is there on the request as null.

In both the above requests when the field is equal to null and when field is not present the **userAssociationStatus** is equal to null. so I can't differentiate what is happening from the request perspective.

The problem is how do I differentiate between the field not being present and the value being passed as null.

Can provide more info if needed.